# Error: link_to delete redirecting to show action instead of going to destroy action in rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

link_to delete redirecting to show action instead of going to destroy action in rails 3.1.1

Here is my code

View:-

> :delete,
>   :confirm => "Are you sure..!", :alt => "Delete", :title => "Delete" %>

Controller:-

> def destroy
>       @industry = Industry.find(params[:id])
>       if @industry.destroy
>         flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted industry with name #{@industry.name}"
>       else
>         flash[:error] = "Error Occurred while deleting industry. Please try again."
>       end
>       redirect_to industries_path
>      end

Comment: Give the code of route.rb and that link_to code.

Comment: Here is the view code

<%= link_to "Delete", industry_path(industry.id), :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure..!", :alt => "Delete", :title => "Delete" %>

Comment: Please give the routing info too. You can use(from terminal) `$ CONTROLLER=controller_name rake routes` to list routing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the default JavaScript libraries loaded?

If not, that'll be why - you can't send a DELETE request through the browser, as it's not supported - so when clicking a delete link, Rails automatically creates a form and sends it that way. But it does that with JS, so if it's not loaded, you'll get nothing.

Comment: hi Stephen
I am using rails 3.1.1, as it dont have any default javascript files.
i tried with including rails.js file in app/assets/javascripts, also included
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "rails" %> in layouts/application.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

Check following code,if the route having

```
DELETE  /industry/:id   destroy .
```

Then

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', industry, confirm: 'Are you sure?',
                                     method: :delete %>
```